# 覗かせている meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning

> 入学当初よりも学力を伸ばし、そして精神面での成長も**覗かせている**須藤は、2年次から記録されていく成績を大きく伸ばすことになりそうだ。

I'm a bit confused with the meaning of 「覗かせている」 in this sentence.

覗く: [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A6%97%E3%81%8F)

1. to peek (through a keyhole, gap, etc.)​,
2. to look down into (a ravine, etc.),
3. to peek into (a shop, bookstore, etc.)​,
4. to sneak a look at; to take a quick look at,
5. to peep (through a telescope, microscope, etc.)​,
6. to stick out (a scarf from a collar, etc.); to peek through (sky through a forest canopy, etc.)​,
7. to examine (an expression); to study (a face)​,
8. to face​Archaism.

Based on the structure of the sentence, I have a feeling that the word 「覗かせている」 means the subject (須藤) shows his growth, rather than other people see his growth.

Please kindly give me your guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the subject (須藤) shows his growth.

Here, the subject of the causative verb のぞかせる is 須藤. And the object of のぞかせる is 精神面での成長. So the subject/agent of のぞく "peep out" is 精神面での成長.

> ［精神面での成長も覗かせている］須藤
>   (≂ 精神面での成長も**見せている**須藤)

⇒ 須藤が(=subject) 精神面での成長**を**(=object) 覗かせている (causative "make something peep out") (も has replaced を in your example)
"Sudo makes his growth peep out" → "Sudo shows his growth"

---

Some examples of this のぞかせる, "make something peep out", i.e. "show", from プログレッシブ和英辞典:

> - 胸のポケットから折り畳んだハンカチを**のぞかせて**、カメラの前に立った。
>     *He faced the camera with a folded handkerchief **peeping out** of his breast pocket.*
>     (Literally: (He) made a folded handkerchief peep out of (his) breast pocket, ...)
> - 太陽が雲間から顔を**のぞかせた**。
>     *The sun **peeped [peeked] out** between the clouds.*
>     (Literally: The sun made its face peep out... → The sun showed its face...)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just say that meaning 6 of the ones Amanda gave is the correct one?